# Use breadcrumbs like a filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is any plugin on rails, to do the same that do the page of [railCast](http://railscasts.com/). Use the tag like a filter.

For example a click in Type  Free Episodes (on the right ) ,on the top of the page appears

Applied Filters: Free Episodes

and with other categories and type the same, and I click the "x" to delete this filter...

any idea!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Those are considered `tags` using the gem `acts-as-taggable-on` (http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging).

You can use a search gem like `solr` or `ransack` (http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) to search on these or build your own search action if you're only searching based on tags.

Answer (score 0):

On the railscasts site there is a type param set, if you click on one of the episode types. There must be an index action which handles the type params - if set, only query the type specific ones, and if not, query all episodes. That´s quite easy. It could look like following for example:

```
class EpisodesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:type]
      @episodes = Episode.where(:specifc_type => params[:type]) 
      # or
      @episodes = Episode.to_klass(params[:type]).all # if you are using STI and have a to_klass method in your model, which generates the class constant out of the params, e.g => params[:type] => "pro", Episode.to_klass("pro") => ProEpisode, or something similar
    else
      @episodes = Episode.all
    end
  end
end
```

And in your view simple render the filter

app/views/episodes/index.html.erb

```
<% if params[:type] %>
  <div class="filters">
    <strong>Applied Filters:</strong>
    <span class="filter">
      <%= your_helper_display_name(params[:type]) %>
      <%= link_to "x", root_path %> # removes the type params => the else case in your index action will be called.
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```